# How do I randomly shuffle a subset of the elements of an existing matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, shuffle

I have a matrix of values ranging from 0 to 3 in Matlab. I want to randomly shuffle the elements of the matrix, but only within the cells that have values in the range 1 -3 (so only within a subset of the whole matrix). Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by getting an index of all the values of interest (such as a [logical index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1)), randomly permuting their order using [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html), then assigning them back into the matrix using the same index:

```
% Sample matrix with values from 0 to 3:
M = randi([0 3], 5)

M =

     3     1     0     3     0
     0     3     3     2     0
     1     0     2     1     0
     1     1     2     2     0
     3     0     0     1     0

index = (M > 0);    % Index of values from 1 to 3
values = M(index);  % Vector of indexed values
M(index) = values(randperm(numel(values)))  % Matrix with shuffled values

M =

     2     3     0     2     0
     0     3     1     1     0
     2     0     3     3     0
     1     1     2     1     0
     3     0     0     1     0
```

Note that the zeroes are all still in the same place in the shuffled matrix. Note also that you still have the same number of ones, twos, and threes, since they are just shuffled to different spots.

Comment: So helpful. Exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you!